# Do we have information about duration time of query in actual execution plan?

Tags: t-sql, execution-plan, xml, time

I am building application in `C#` which is parsing Actual Execution Plan. I need basic stats like `Row count`, `CPU time`, `Page Reads` etc. All above stats I found in `XML` of Actual Execution Plan. I can not find time duration of executed query. Do you know If it is possible to retrieve it ?

Answer (score 2):

It should be the node `QueryTimeStats` there will be a section for `CPUTime` and `ElapsedTime`. The time is in milleseconds.

`CPUTime` may be longer than `ElapsedTime` due to the query going parallel across multiple CPU cores, this is expected behavior.

`ElapsedTime` may be longer than `CPUTime` when a query is blocked, or waiting on non-CPU resources to complete. Things like reading pages from disk into memory, or writing to the transaction log, etc.

You may want to try to parse the `WaitStats` section of the XML for additional details on this, but be aware that it does not include *all* waits. For example, lock waits and `CXCONSUMER` are not included in the collection.